# How do I run the same code on multiple data frames?

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a list of data frames imported from a folder and I want to write a function that will change some values depending on the title of the data frame (which is taken from the filename).

```
library(dplyr)

time_geog <- function(index) {
  index = index %>%
    mutate(Quarter = quarter(as.Date(quarter_date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
                             with_year = TRUE),
           Quarter = paste0(substr(as.character(Quarter), 1, 4),"Q",
                            substr(as.character(Quarter), 6, 6)),
           QuarterQF = case_when(Quarter == "2018Q4" ~ "p",
                                 TRUE ~ ""))
  if(str_detect(index, "Title")) {
    index = index %>% 
      mutate(var1 = case_when(var1 == "abcd" ~ "code",
                                             TRUE ~ var1),
             var2 = case_when(var2 == "abcd" ~ "code",
                                           TRUE ~ var2),
             QF1 = case_when(var1 %in% c("value1", "value2") ~ "x",
                                   TRUE ~ ""),
             QF2 = case_when(var2 %in% c("value1", "value2") ~ "x",
                                   TRUE ~ ""))
  } else {
    index = index %>%
      mutate(var3 = case_when(var3 == "abcd" ~ "code",
                                 TRUE ~ var3),
             var4 = case_when(var4 == "abcd" ~ "code",
                                  TRUE ~ var4),
             QF1 = case_when(var3 == "value1" ~ "d", TRUE ~ "",
                                  var3 %in% c("value2", "value3") ~ "x",
                                  TRUE ~ ""))
  }
}
```

I've put this function into a for loop, as below, which also reads in all files I need and assigns them a name based on their original name.

```
for (i in names) {
  filepath <- file.path(files, paste0(i, ".csv"))
  assign(substr(i, 10, nchar(i)), read_csv(filepath)) 
  time_geog(get(substr(i, 10, nchar(i))))
}
```

It works when I pass a specific file to it, but not when I run the loop. I also have no problems reading in the files that I need with the titles that I need. I don't want them all in the same data frame afterwards either, which is what happens if I use:

```
for (i in names) {
  filepath <- file.path(files, paste0(i, ".csv"))
  assign(substr(i, 10, nchar(i)), read_csv(filepath)) 
  i <- time_geog(get(substr(i, 10, nchar(i))))
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I feel like I'm really close but just missing some vital piece of knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Always remember the correct way of manipulating many dataframes at a time is to store them into a list, and then apply your function to the list at one time using `lapply` or other mapping functions.

I don't have your data, but based on your provided code, you can try:

```
# create an empty list (you may want to specify the length of the list if you know the total number of your files)   
df_list <- list()

# store all dataframe into the list
for (i in names) {
  filepath <- file.path(files, paste0(i, ".csv"))
  df_list[[length(df_list)+1]] <- read_csv(filepath) 
}

# apply your function to the list
df_list_new <- lapply(df_list,time_geog)

# merge the list into one master dataframe (`bind_rows()` comes from `dplyr` package)
df_master <- bind_rows(df_list_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention *"list of data frames"* but your code shows you using `assign`, which I generally discourage. If your frames are similar-enough, then you could get your list with

```r
list_of_frames <- setNames(lapply(paste0(files, ".csv"), readr::read_csv),
                           files)
```

(or some `substr` of the file names).

Your function is hoping to get the *name* of the object by matching on the object itself. While there are ways to do it (something like `deparse`/`substitute`, not the way you're attempting), it won't work in all cases and I suggest that it should not be relied on.

Instead, I suggest your function should be given the name with the data. Perhaps something like this (untested):

```r
time_geog <- function(index, name) {
  index = index %>%
    mutate(Quarter = quarter(as.Date(quarter_date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
                             with_year = TRUE),
           Quarter = paste0(substr(as.character(Quarter), 1, 4),"Q",
                            substr(as.character(Quarter), 6, 6)),
           QuarterQF = case_when(Quarter == "2018Q4" ~ "p",
                                 TRUE ~ ""))
  if(str_detect(name, "Title")) {
    index = index %>% 
      mutate(var1 = case_when(var1 == "abcd" ~ "code",
                                             TRUE ~ var1),
             var2 = case_when(var2 == "abcd" ~ "code",
                                           TRUE ~ var2),
             QF1 = case_when(var1 %in% c("value1", "value2") ~ "x",
                                   TRUE ~ ""),
             QF2 = case_when(var2 %in% c("value1", "value2") ~ "x",
                                   TRUE ~ ""))
  } else {
    index = index %>%
      mutate(var3 = case_when(var3 == "abcd" ~ "code",
                                 TRUE ~ var3),
             var4 = case_when(var4 == "abcd" ~ "code",
                                  TRUE ~ var4),
             QF1 = case_when(var3 == "value1" ~ "d", TRUE ~ "",
                                  var3 %in% c("value2", "value3") ~ "x",
                                  TRUE ~ ""))
  }
  return(index)
}
out <- Map(time_geog, list_of_frames, files)
```